# Image Slider / carousel not render while user move from one page to other - Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

There are multiple pages (Home & Product detail page) in my application and each page has carousel with multiple images . When i browse application home page whole page is loaded and all js & carousel js working fine and carousel initialized without any error  .

But when i clicks on any product detail page then angular updates center part of page while header & footer remains same .

Issue -  carousel is not initialized at product detail page and all images display individually instead of carousel .

- All js & css are include in src/app/index.html not in angular.json

Comment: It's difficult imagine your application for me, but I think you need subscribe in ngOnInit to router.ParamsMap to initialize your carousel acording the params https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action

Comment: How are you implementing the carousel, which plugins, what is the code? Please mention all these so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are rendering your carousel in angular code, try using owl-carousel with angular 6 .

Install a package using 
 npm install ngx-owl-carousel 
 owl.carousel jquery --save

For more details please refer:-
https://medium.com/@biswa8998/owl-carousel-with-angular-6-banner-slider-and-image-carousel-3b3ded0070c5

Comment: Thanks For reply. I used owl.carousel  and it implemented successfully but issue is that once we reload whole page via F5 or refresh button then carousel works but when i navigate to pages via website links then carousel not rendered . How to initialize owl.carousel  after navigate via links

Comment: Did you use owlRouterLink , look for this example :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o

Comment: I did not use owlRouterLink because i have not idea about it . can you provide me code around owlRouterLink. that will be helpful for me.

Comment: Example below: -<a [owlRouterLink]="['/present']" [stopLink]="isDragging">{{item.text}}</a>